# Can I connect my Windows 8.1 laptop to my Pi via WIFI?

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh, wireless, putty

My laptop does not have an ethernet port and I also do not have a USB-to-Ethernet port adapter but what I do have is a WIFI dongle for my pi. I was thinking, can I possibly connect to my pi via WIFI like an ethernet connection so that I can SSH via PuTTy?

Comment: Assuming that your laptop has WiFi and the Pi also has WiFi and they are both on the same network you will be able to connect. This is much simpler if there is a router involved, but can be done with point to point networking or setting one up as an access point.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your laptop and your pi are both connected to the same router.
2. Test your Internet connection by pinging, for example, http://google.com on both devices. (`ping google.com`)
3. On your Pi, in a terminal, type in `ifconfig`.
4. Look for `inet addr:192.168.*.*`, and remember that set of numbers (or write them down). That is your Pi's IP address.
5. In your laptop, start PuTTY.
6. Type the set of numbers you saw in step 4 into the host name field.
7. If you want, you can save the settings so you don't have to type the IP address in every time you want to remotely connect to your pi.
8. Hit "Open".
9. Enter the user name and password of your Pi.
10. Enjoy the command line of your Pi!

Comment: Hello, ping does not require the `http://` in fact it is not working that way. Feel free to edit your answer.

Comment: I think he wants to use his Pi as an access point....

Comment: @ppumkin, not necessarily. I think all of the options that Steve mentioned may apply. This answer addresses just one of those options (which is not a bad thing).

Answer (score 0):

A great tool to discover your Pi (and all your other devices), and it's IP number on your network is **Fing**: https://www.fingbox.com/download.

Once you have connection, then SSH and VNC become y our new best friends.

Available on :

- Android - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en_GB
- iOS - https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107?mt=8

Both free and paid plans are available. I am not affiliated in any way with Fing.

Comment: You might want to include that this product comes with a plan and monthly payments. If you're related to the product/company (which I do not know) you'll have to [disclose that too](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).